# How do i make a grid responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

i'm working on a **css grid design** and it's working fine on desktop view. ¿How do i make it responsive?

I buld a section with a background image, later i add several articles to display a grid over the image. And like i said works fine on desktop but in responsive it's not look fine.

I would like to know how to make it responsive.

Thanks a lot

*Here is my css code:*

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #cuadricula {
        width: 600px;
        height: 900px;
        display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
        grid-gap: 1px;
        background: #c51162;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #cuadricula__img {
        width: 600px;
        height: 900px;
        object-fit: cover;
        grid-row: 1 / 8;
        grid-column: 1/3;
    }

    .item_cuadricula_1,
    .item_cuadricula_2,
    .item_cuadricula_3,
    .item_cuadricula_4,
    .item_cuadricula_5,
    .item_cuadricula_6,
    .item_cuadricula_7,
    .item_cuadricula_8,
    .item_cuadricula_9,
    .item_cuadricula_10,
    .item_cuadricula_11,
    .item_cuadricula_12,
    .item_cuadricula_13,
    .item_cuadricula_14,
    .item_cuadricula_15,
    .item_cuadricula_16,
    .item_cuadricula_17,
    .item_cuadricula_18,
    .item_cuadricula_19,
    .item_cuadricula_20,
    .item_cuadricula_21,
    .item_cuadricula_22,
    .item_cuadricula_23,
    .item_cuadricula_24,
    .item_cuadricula_25,
    .item_cuadricula_26,
    .item_cuadricula_27 {
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        /*            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);*/
    }

    .item_cuadricula_1 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        background: rgba(253, 85, 143, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_2 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 1;
        background: rgba(0, 57, 203, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_3 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 1;
        background: rgba(0, 150, 36, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_4 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2;
        background: rgba(199, 165, 0, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_5 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2;
        background: rgba(135, 0, 0, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_6 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 2;
        background: rgba(103, 218, 255, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_7 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 3;
        background: rgba(175, 68, 72, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_8 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 3;
        background: rgba(240, 98, 146, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_9 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 3;
        background: rgba(186, 104, 200, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_10 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 4;
        background: rgba(255, 241, 118, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_11 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 4;
        background: rgba(181, 61, 0, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_12 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 4;
        background: rgba(62, 39, 35, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_13 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 5;
        background: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_14 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 5;
        background: rgba(0, 178, 204, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_15 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 5;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 114, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_16 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 6;
        background: rgba(255, 241, 118, 0.60);

    }

    .item_cuadricula_17 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 6;
        background: rgba(82, 76, 0, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_18 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 6;
        background: rgba(157, 70, 255, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_19 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 7;
        background: rgba(172, 8, 0, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_20 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 7;
        background: rgba(0, 136, 163, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_21 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 7;
        background: rgba(197, 17, 98, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_22 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 8;
        background: rgba(186, 104, 200, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_23 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 8;
        background: rgba(253, 85, 143, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_24 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 8;
        background: rgba(0, 57, 203, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_25 {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 9;
        background: rgba(0, 150, 36, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_26 {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 9;
        background: rgba(0, 178, 204, 0.60);
    }

    .item_cuadricula_27 {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 9;
        background: rgba(10, 0, 182, 0.60);
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        #cuadricula {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #cuadricula__img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 900px;
        }
        .item_cuadricula_1,
        .item_cuadricula_2,
        .item_cuadricula_3,
        .item_cuadricula_4,
        .item_cuadricula_5,
        .item_cuadricula_6,
        .item_cuadricula_7,
        .item_cuadricula_8,
        .item_cuadricula_9,
        .item_cuadricula_10,
        .item_cuadricula_11,
        .item_cuadricula_12,
        .item_cuadricula_13,
        .item_cuadricula_14,
        .item_cuadricula_15,
        .item_cuadricula_16,
        .item_cuadricula_17,
        .item_cuadricula_18,
        .item_cuadricula_19,
        .item_cuadricula_20,
        .item_cuadricula_21,
        .item_cuadricula_22,
        .item_cuadricula_23,
        .item_cuadricula_24,
        .item_cuadricula_25,
        .item_cuadricula_26,
        .item_cuadricula_27 {
            background: none;
        }
        body {
            font-size: 0.5em;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:1920px) {}
```

And here is my HTML

```
 <section id="cuadricula">
    <img src="Wonder-Woman-2017-Poster-dceu-dc-extended-universe-41499151-1382-2048.jpg" alt="Cachorro" id="cuadricula__img">


    <article class="item_cuadricula_1">fila 1 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_2">fila 1 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_3">fila 1 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_4">fila 2 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_5">fila 2 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_6">fila 2 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_7">fila 3 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_8">fila 3 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_9">fila 3 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_10">fila 4 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_11">fila 4 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_12">fila 4 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_13">fila 5 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_14">fila 5 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_15">fila 5 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_16">fila 6 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_17">fila 6 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_18">fila 6 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_19">fila 7 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_20">fila 7 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_21">fila 7 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_22">fila 8 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_23">fila 8 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_24">fila 8 columna 3</article>

    <article class="item_cuadricula_25">fila 9 columna 1</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_26">fila 9 columna 2</article>
    <article class="item_cuadricula_27">fila 9 columna 3</article>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify grid-row and grid-column in this situation since they are just going one after another. 
When you make a `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` it arranges all grid elements in 3 columns in every row.
And you don't have to specify row template because the grid will go as long as there are enough elements using column template.
Then you should find screen widths where it starts to fall apart and change grid-column-template from 1fr 1fr 1fr to 1fr 1fr (or similar). 
If you want the image to be your #cuadricula background, you should not add a new `<img>` in HTML, but make the image a background-image of your element.
So your code should get responsive if you write your css like this:

```
#cuadricula {
        width: 600px;
        height: 900px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;  
        background: #c51162;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url('http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/Simple.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .item_cuadricula_1 {
        background: rgba(253, 85, 143, 0.60);
    }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
        #cuadricula {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you could see the result here [link](https://codepen.io/gatocode2016/pen/YdapBW). Regards